# Socket leak with wait_for in asyncio with python3.6 and python3.7

Tags: python, python-asyncio

In some cases `asyncio.wait_for` can lead to socket leak.

Condensed example:

```py
async def _create_connection(timeout=60, ssl_obj):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    connector = loop.create_connection(MyEchoClientProtocol, '127.0.0.1', 5000, ssl=ssl_obj)
    connector = asyncio.ensure_future(connector)
    tr, pr = await asyncio.wait_for(connector, timeout=timeout, loop=loop)
    return tr, pr

async def main():
    ...
    res = await asyncio.wait_for(_acquire_impl(), timeout=timeout, loop=loop)
```

If my understanding is correct `wait_for` should work in exactly 2 ways

1. the inner task is completed and the outer task will receive the result – transport and protocol in this case
2. The inner task is cancelled and no connection was established

I provided source code for client and server so the problem can be easily reproduced on your system.

certificate and key can be easily generated with `minica`

I found out that if I catch `CancelledError` and add a `done_callback` to the inner task, like so:

```py
    try:
        tr, pr = await asyncio.wait_for(connector, timeout=timeout, loop=loop)
        return tr, pr
    except asyncio.CancelledError as e:
        connector.add_done_callback(_done_callback)
        raise e
```

then inside of `_done_callback` I can access the transport and protocol object and close the transport manually to prevent leaking:

Client

```py
import asyncio
import io
import struct
import functools
import ssl as ssl_module
import socket
import collections
import time
import traceback

class MyEchoClientProtocol(asyncio.Protocol):

    def connection_made(self, transport):
        print('connection_made', transport)
        query = 'hello world'
        transport.write(query.encode('latin-1'))

    def data_received(self, data):
        print('data_received', data)

    def connection_lost(self, exc):
        print('connection_lost', exc)


async def create_connection(ssl_obj, timeout=60):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    connector = loop.create_connection(MyEchoClientProtocol, '127.0.0.1', 5000, ssl=ssl_obj)
    connector = asyncio.ensure_future(connector)
    tr, pr = await asyncio.wait_for(connector, timeout=timeout, loop=loop)
    return tr, pr

async def main(timeout, ssl_obj):
    async def _acquire_impl():
        try:
            proxy = await create_connection(ssl_obj) 
        except Exception:
            raise
        else:
            return proxy

    res = await asyncio.wait_for(_acquire_impl(), timeout=timeout, loop=loop)
    return res

async def test_cancel():
    sc = ssl_module.create_default_context(ssl_module.Purpose.SERVER_AUTH, cafile='localhostc.crt')
    sc.check_hostname = False
    sc.verify_mode = ssl_module.CERT_NONE
    for i in range(10): # try 50 times
        timeout = 0.003
        try:
            tr, pr = await main(
                timeout=timeout, ssl_obj=sc
            )
            tr.close()
        except asyncio.TimeoutError as e:
            print('timeouterror', repr(e))
    await asyncio.sleep(600)


import asyncio
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(test_cancel())
loop.run_forever()
loop.close()
```

Server

```py
import asyncio
import ssl

async def handle_echo(reader, writer):
    data = await reader.read(100)
    message = data.decode()
    addr = writer.get_extra_info('peername')
    print("Received %r from %r" % (message, addr))

    print("Send: %r" % message)
    writer.write(data)
    await writer.drain()


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

sc = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
sc.load_cert_chain('localhost.crt', 'localhost.key')

coro = asyncio.start_server(handle_echo, '127.0.0.1', 5000, loop=loop, ssl=sc)
server = loop.run_until_complete(coro)

try:
    loop.run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

# Close the server
server.close()
loop.run_until_complete(server.wait_closed())
loop.close()
```

I run `netstat -a | grep 5000 | grep ESTAB | awk '{ print $5 }' | sort | uniq -c | grep 5000` after the script is done and there are many unclosed connections.

The output depends on your hardware so you might need to tweak the timeout parameter

**The Questions**

1. Why can this happen?
2. Is it an expected behaviour? Maybe I'm missing something fundamental about asyncio and python.
3. What is correct method to prevent leaking sockets while using timeout?

**Environment**
OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
python: Python 3.6.6 or Python 3.7.3

Comment: While fascinating and perhaps a bug, you don't actually *ask a question* here. Perhaps you should instead report this to the [Python bug tracker](https://stackoverflow.com/admin/cm-message/6595)?

Comment: I've added the questions

Comment: Is SSL strictly necessary? Can this be reproduced with the SSL context stripped from your examples? Please minimise the code as much as possible, if there is no need to generate a certificate just to reproduce this then all the better.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce it without ssl, but it does not prove anything. SSL connection takes more time to establish so it's probably easier to find timeout parameter that works. I'll try to remove ssl, but for now I wasn't able to do so.